# A way to avoid asInstanceOf in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I have this hierarchy of traits and classes in Scala:

```
trait A
trait B[T] extends A {
  def v: T
}
case class C(v:Int) extends B[Int]
case class D(v:String) extends B[String]
val l:List[A] = C(1) :: D("a") :: Nil
l.foreach(t => println(t.asInstanceOf[B[_]].v))
```

I cannot change the type hierarchy or the type of the list.

Is there a better way to avoid the asInstanceOf[B[_]] statement?

Comment: Can you declare the list `l` as `List[B[_]]` right from the beginning, instead explicitly declaring it as `List[A]`?

Comment: If you can not change the type of the list, how are you sure all instances will be of type `B`? What should happen if any instance is not of type `B`?, Ignore it and continue? Fail with an exception?

Comment: I cannot change the type of the list. Just ignore if something is not of type B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
for (x <- l.view; y <- Some(x).collect { case b: B[_] => b }) println(y.v)
```

It doesn't require any `isInstanceOf` or `asInstanceOf`, and never crashes, even if your list contains `A`s that aren't `B[_]`s. It also doesn't create any lengthy lists as intermediate results, only small short-lived `Option`s.

---

Not as concise, but also much less surprising solution:

```
for (x <- l) {
  x match {
    case b: B[_] => println(b.v)
    case _ => /* do nothing */
  }
}
```

---

If you could change the type of `l` to `List[B[_]]`, this would be the preferable solution.

Comment: In case the upvote/unupvote was caused by the doubt whether the refutable pattern `b: B[_]` can be used in `for` directly to add a `withFilter` step: apparently it cannot: `for (b: B[_] <- l) { ... }` doesn't compile. At least I don't know how to force it to compile.

Answer (score 6):

You might try pattern matching.

```
l.collect{case x :B[_] => println(x.v)}
```

Comment: This crashes with a `MatchError` if the list is not actually `List[B[_]]`.

Comment: Ok... Why are you collecting lists of useless `()`-values now?

Comment: I let my cat play with them before I throw them away.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most ideomatic way to do it would be to supply `B` with an extractor object and pattern match for `B` values:

```scala
object B {
    def unapply[T](arg: B[T]): Some[T] =  Some(arg.v)
  }
l.collect{case B(x) => println(x)}
```

If `B` is declared in a  source file you can't alter you might need a different name for the extractor object.